# DHCP Requests leaking through VPN

Tags: router, dhcp, openvpn, tomato

I have a spread-out setup to deal with: 3 off-site buildings with Tomato Firmware-based routers, connecting to another Tomato-based router as a VPN setup. The Server router is also in our private LAN network (as an edge device).

In our main LAN, we have a DHCP server running on a Linux server, offering 192.168.0.0/19 (yes, subnet mask is 255.255.224.0!), with the 192.168.2.x/24 octet being excluded. At each site, each Tomato VPN Client (the routers from now on) are supposed to offer IPs in a certain range to their clients within the 192.168.2.x subnet. SiteA is 192.168.2.2-29 (router is .1), SiteB is 192.168.2.31-50 (router is .30), and SiteC is 192.168.2.52-80 (.51 is the router). The computers can connect to our server with no issue.

What is happening though, is that all of a sudden (when this worked perfectly fine before), I have the router from SiteA offering leases to clients at other sites. Because they are in the same ultimate network (192.168.0.0/19), they can access servers in our LAN, but not the Internet.

As a temporary fix, I could remote in to the computers at SiteB and SiteC, and assign the default gateway to be the routers at each location. This is not a good fix though, as it prevents other staff from visiting the site with their laptops or tablets, and being able to connect right away.

The routers are not compiled with support for `ebtables` as recommended in a few other threads. The ultimate goal is to have the DHCP servers only offer leases on the LAN side of their own routers.

**Router B's VPN Client configuration**
[image]
[image]

**Router A's VPN Client configuration** (*The Redirect Internet Traffic was originally disabled; it was enabled above just for testing*)
[image]
[image]

Comment: sorry, DHCP uses layer2 broadcasts, so you cannot scope a server in that manner, other than by blocking DHCP requests crossing the VPN.

Comment: @FrankThomas How could I go about doing that? I have SSH access to each of the routers, if that helps

Comment: well, I would implement a firewall at each VPN gateway and having it drop all UDP\67-68 traffic it sees crossing from the VPN to locallan and viceversa. It sounds like your routers do not have the firewall modules installed however, so that makes it more difficult.

Comment: Is are clients at both site B and C receiving IP assignments from site A, or just one of them (B or C)? Is DHCP working at the other site(s), i.e. if manually attempted, does the router hand out IPs? My point is, that maybe the clients are going all the way to site A because their local router didn't respond or denied the request.

Comment: And, as already mentioned, separating sites by subnet is the correct way, and avoids many headaches

Comment: @Dr.Ping Good question. I checked, and the only MAC address that's being blocked is a cell phone (we don't allow mobile phones on our networks). I can't separate them into separate subnets until at least the summer (it's a school)

Comment: @CanadianLuke i suggest that you go ahead and try it. Take site A's router offline, and see if clients at site B and C get DHCP assignments. Sometime at night....

Comment: I have no access to them after hours, but I'll try remotely

Comment: I should still add though, that I'm not on the level of the other commentors. These configs are beyond my knowledge (as of current....). I just think that some of the simpler things do come to mind as well.

Answer (score 2):

Your VPN is TAP, assuming that OpenVPN is the underlying tech, then this means you have a layer2 VPN.  That means you have things setup as if they were all physically connected to the same switch.  If you don't want a layer2 network, don't use TAP.

Comment: Would TUN (the only other option) still allow what I want, where the clients can all see each other through each site? And have Internet access?

Comment: If you setup your routes properly.  A tun network is the better solution, it just is a bit more complicated.  The complicating factor, is that I am not sure if you can do it with tomato.  I am completely certain that the underlying OpenVPN supports it though.  You would also need to change your network a bit, so that the remote sites are on separate subnets.

Comment: And I can't change our network scheme for the next few months, unfortunately :-(

Comment: Ah, you have a challenging problem then.  I am not sure what to suggest.  DHCP is probably mostly working for you, because DHCP clients will usually just accept the fastest reply, which will usually be from the physically closest DHCP server.